# How to check if string contains the text in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me in writing a piece of code in C# Winforms, which can give me a boolean value, that whether a piece of string contains a few words.

For example, If I want to check whether string **test only string** exists in string "Data is provided to test only string".

I have written following piece of code, but it alwys gives me true, whether string contains the words or nor.

```
    private bool ContainsText(string input)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (((int)input[i] >= 65 && (int)input[i] <= 90) || ((int)input[i] >= 97 && (int)input[i] <= 177))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

When I call the following line, I always get **true**, which is not correct

```
MessageBox.Show(ContainsText("test only string").ToString());
```

Comment: There's a String.Contains method ya know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Contains method of String object.

```
var a = "Data is provided to test only string";
var b = "test only string";

if (a.Contains(b))
     MessageBox.Show("yes");
```

Answer (score 2):

Code-wise, your `ContainsText` code *immediately* returns `true` if *any* character in `input` is either in "A to Z" or "a to U+00B1" for some reason.

But the problems lie deeper than that: you've described *two* inputs - the string to check for, e.g. "test only string" and the string to check for its presence, e.g. "Data is provided to test only string". Your method only accepts *one* input, and doesn't use any other state. So it can't *possibly* work. It's worth taking a step back and trying to work out why you didn't notice that you needed two inputs - and why indeed your test only used "test only string" and didn't mention "Data is provided to test only string".

You don't really need a method at all though - `String` already has a [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method:

```
if (textToCheck.Contains(textToFind))
{
    ...
}
```

That's assuming you want an ordinal comparison. Use `IndexOf` with an appropriate `StringComparison` if you want to check in a culture-sensitive or case-insensitive way.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) perhaps with the enum to ignore case:

```
 string myTestString = "Data is provided to Test Only String";
 if(myTestString.IndexOf("test only string", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Found text");
```

Of course the string class has also a Contains method, but it is implemented as a call to IndexOf, without the possibility to ignore the case.

```
public bool Contains(string value)
{
     return (this.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IndexOf

http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof

example of usage..

```
string str = "string to test";
bool result = str.IndexOf("The hosted network started.") != -1;

MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```